# Event prediction sequence

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, prediction

I need to create an app to predict events.

I'll explain my requirements: I have a set of intermediate events (eg.: 1, 2, 3...9) and a set of final events (eg.: A for OK and B for KO). These events bring a correlation id to relate each other.

What ML algorithm can I use to predict if a sequence of events could cause a future KO event (B in my example) or not?

I need an unsupervised algorithm.

Any idea about the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sequential association rules could be applied here. Please check [spmf](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/index.php?link=documentation.php) java library, section 'Sequential Rule Mining'.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a simple clustering algorithm such as k-Means?

Another idea is "Isolation Forest" on SK-Learn. Rather than clustering, you're looking for anomalies in your dataset and classify accordingly.

Good luck!